# Font that looks like another font or how to edit the font

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I found a font recently and I really like it, but the numbers in the font don't look right, so I was wondering if I could post a question about either finding a font that looks the same but has numbers that fit in better with the alphanumeric characters or how I might go about editing the font to make the numbers look the way I like.

Is such a question appropriate? I intend to mention the name of the font, include screenshots of it and describe what I want to use it for.

I feel that it's not necessarily a question about graphic design but it's likely to be something that graphics designers would be able to help with.

I don't want to identify the font, I'm looking for a similar font or even the same font but with different numeric characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We accept (and encourage!) questions about typography in general, so yours would be a good fit (as long as you describe what your issue / goal is).

These are some examples of similar questions:

- [What are best practices for choosing and pairing fonts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-best-practices-for-choosing-and-pairing-fonts)
- [Web Safe Alternative to Myriad Pro Font?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/350/web-safe-alternative-to-myriad-pro-font)
- [What are some typefaces to pair with Bauhaus?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20413/what-are-some-typefaces-to-pair-with-bauhaus)
- [Visually similar alternatives to Helvetica?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/602/visually-similar-alternatives-to-helvetica)

So feel free to ask :)

Comment: I would add that unless the rights allow alteration, any suggestions for editing the font must be purely hypothetical. Creating a derivative work from a copyright source is not permitted in most jurisdictions.